# idn domain not showing correct in firefox

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

I have bought this domain bilvärdering.nu

```
http://xn--bilvrdering-o8a.nu/
```

in firefox adressbar it show up like 
http://xn--bilvrdering-o8a.nu/
but in chrome and IE it show up with the correct characters

```
http://bilvärdering.nu/
```

How can I make firefox show correct characters in its adressbar?

Answer (score 1):

It's a security feature: 
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.IDN_show_punycode

The reason is, that there exist unicode characters that look exactly like latin characters, but would point to a totally different domain if used in an URL, allowing for phishing attacks.